# Can someone please help me translate this line from a manga I'm reading?

Tags: translation, manga

> お前だってもうずっと俺以外の血を望まなかった

I'm basically torn between two interpretations:

1. You haven't wanted any one's blood but mine for a while now
2. You've never wanted any one's blood but mine

Answer (score 3):

(もう)ずっと～しない / (もう)ずっと～していない means "have not done ～ for a while." So this sentence means 1. That is, this person(?) wanted (and probably actually enjoyed) someone else's blood a long time ago, but it's been long since he did so last.

> もうずっと彼に会っていない。
>   I haven't seen him for a long time.